# The "key" in Laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 models: `Invoice` and `InvoiceItems` and these models are connected with `invoice_id`:

```
 Schema::create('invoice_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('invoice_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign("invoice_id")->references('id')->on('invoices')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

`Invoice` :

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'profile_id',
        'invoice_number',
         ....
    ];

    public function invoiceItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\InvoiceItem');
    }
 }
```

And `InvoiceItems`

```
class InvoiceItem extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
    } 
}
```

When I want to get an invoice with it's invoice items using eloquent, I use the following code:

```
$invoice = Invoice::with('invoiceItems')->findOrFail($id);
```

now the output of `dd($invoice->toArray())` is:

```
array:20 [▼
  "id" => 14
  "profile_id" => 13
  "invoice_number" => null
  ....
  "created_at" => "2020-05-05 09:21:46"
  "updated_at" => "2020-05-09 12:09:14"
  "invoice_items" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:10 [▼
      "id" => 9
      "invoice_id" => 14
      "price" => "10000.00"
      "created_at" => "2020-05-05 09:21:46"
      "updated_at" => "2020-05-05 09:21:46"
    ]
  ]
]
```

till now everything looks great, but I'm confused! when I want to use `$invoice->invoice_items` it returns `null` while it exists in the top `dd($invoice->toArray())`!
On the other hand when I use `$invoice->invoiceItems` it works well!
now whats the reason of this difference?

Comment: camelCase relationships are converted to snake_case probably because that's the naming convention for database columns and relationships are treated as though they are a column in the table

Comment: `$invoice->invoice_items[0]` try this

Comment: @A.ANoman Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: @apokryfos you're right

Comment: Sorry. This is relational value @soheilyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$invoice->invoiceItems` instead.

you can find it in the relationships attribute I think.

To array executes laravel logic, they choose to include everything as kebab_case to keep it consistent datawise, but I understand your confusion.

Comment: thanks! but after your answer I've tested this code: `$invoice = Invoice::with('invoiceItems')->findOrFail($id);
        $invoice->camelCase = "camelCase";
        dd($invoice->toArray());`  and I expected to receive : camel_case in output, but I didn't: `array:21 [▼
  "id" => 15
  "created_at" => "2020-05-05 09:27:06"
  "updated_at" => "2020-05-10 06:23:58"
  "camelCase" => "camelCase"
  "invoice_items" => array:1 [▶]
]`

Comment: I mean it seems that it does not returns to `toArray()' alone

Comment: @shoheil here you are explicitly setting an attribute camelcase. Here no key translation is done (by default) but relationships are included kebab case

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel's Eloquent ORM, the "key" refers to the column or attribute used to establish a relationship between two database tables.

**Here's an example of a relationship definition in an Eloquent model:**

```
 class Post extends Model
 {
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
        }
 }
```